# Invalid address error on a call of the contract which has been deployed and mined

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I deployed private test network, but at this moment have an issue to call the contract method.

Contracts had been successfully deployed on the ```private testnet`` with help of hardhat:

```
npx hardhat run --network privateNet scripts/deploy.ts
```

Later it was successfully mined:

```
$txpool.status
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 0
}
$eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xfd76b6d85cec7352fc81414447ec261b377191c7c3251e2c3a680f448278a2cd")
{
  blockHash: "0x775c67215566ae151cabf99a9f2b0fd3506e0c5da26ed4fd985be020e53ba64a",
  blockNumber: 1039,
  contractAddress: "0xdb0a70d30cbcb6553b63862393823a227f3b9aae",
  cumulativeGasUsed: 10399528,
  effectiveGasPrice: 1000000000,
  from: "0x62f8dc8a5c80db6e8fcc042f0cc54a298f8f2ffd",
  gasUsed: 92727,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  status: "0x1",
  to: null,
  transactionHash: "0xfd76b6d85cec7352fc81414447ec261b377191c7c3251e2c3a680f448278a2cd",
  transactionIndex: 4,
  type: "0x0"
}
```

Seems everything is correct here. Next I get a contract instance and execute a call where I get an error:

```
infoFeedContract.at("0xdb0a70d30cbcb6553b63862393823a227f3b9aae").info()
Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (web3.js:3940:11(45))
    at inputTransactionFormatter (web3.js:3756:41(14))
    at web3.js:5043:37(8)
```

Error points out on invalid address, but  the only address has used here is address of the contract and if you look again `tx receipt` this contract already has been mined.

Do you see the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lays here:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase
```

Later you will have to unlock the account which runs the tx, but it error message in that case is more explanatory:

```
personal.unlockAccount("0x62f8dc8a5c80db6e8fcc042f0cc54a298f8f2ffd")
```

Also my private network was launched over `--http` and for this mode unlock account is forbidden for security reasons. As a temporary solution was a launch with this flag:

```
 --allow-insecure-unlock
```